# Компилятор выдает вот такую ошибку. decloration 'array' as array of references. Не подскажите как исправить?

Tags: c++, функции

```
void Clear(int as[4][4], int& array[10][24],int x,int y)
{
 for (int i=0;i++;i<4)
  for(int j=0;j++;j<4)
  {
  if (as[i][j]==2) array[x+i][y+j]=0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

например вот так (там ещё и цикл  немного исправлен)

```
void Clear(int as[4][4], int(& array)[10][24],int x,int y)
{
 for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
  for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
  {
  if (as[i][j]==2) array[x+i][y+j]=0;
  }
}
```

P.S.

> decl**o**ration 'array' as array of references.

компилятор сами исправите

Answer (score 1):

Ну, вы объявили массив ссылок. Если же вы хотите объявить ссылку на массив - то надо писать

```
void Clear(int as[4][4], int(& array)[10][24],int x,int y)
```